Should I use ZORA/DKH for my geometry optimization, or only for TD-DFT?
ORCA has implemented a scalar relativistic contracted version of def2-TZVP (with DKH or ZORA), which I used to study a copper-phenantroline system (for geometry optimization and TD-DFT).
My question is whether I should actually make use of it thoroughly (for geometry optimization + TD-DFT) or should I do the optimization run without it, and just apply it for TD-DFT (this question arose from the example from here.
Thanks

I recommend neither the zero-order approximation (ZORA), nor the finite-order DKH approximations.
The X2C method is far superior to both, and essentially costs the same. The  spin-free 1-electron X2C method is equivalent to infinite-order DKH, so instead of doing DK2, DK3, DK4, ... DK10 and checking for convergence, you can just do one X2C calculation.
You also asked whether to use the X2C Hamiltonian for just the single-point energy at the optimized geometry, or to do the full geometry optimization with X2C. The cost of doing an X2C calculation is not much different from doing a non-relativistic calculation, especially if you use a basis set that is contracted for the X2C Hamiltonian, such as cc-pVTZ-X2C.
I often use an uncontracted basis set for my X2C calculations, in which case the geometry optimization would be faster (and perhaps more stable due to less opportunities for linear dependencies, for example) if I did it with a basis set that is contracted for a non-relativistic Hamiltonian, but those calculations with uncontracted basis sets were for when I was trying to do ultra-high accuracy calculations on small systems (e.g. single atoms or dinuclear molecules). For your relatively large system, I would just use a basis set that is contracted for the X2C Hamiltonian, and do the full geometry-optimization and single-point TD-DFT calculation using the X2C Hamiltonian, since that would be the most accurate option out of the ones discussed in the title of your question and in my answer.
Plenty of free software such as PySCF and CFOUR can do X2C calculations, so if your software can only do ZORA and DKH, then it might be time to change your software.

Orca 5.0 doesn't have X2C yet. It will be in Orca 6.0 to be released soon. Therefore, right now I need to stick with either ZORA or DKH.

@farmaceut The good news is that you only have to wait two more weeks to get ORCA 6.0 (https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=11506, requires login to see). This also means that you don't have to change your software :)

@wzkchem5 good to know! wondering what they introduce.
